# MongoDB query help: update element in a nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a 'schedule'. The building, room etc. may or may not already exist.

This is the call I'm using:

```
var query ={code: dayObj.code, rooms: {$elemMatch: {name: dayObj.room, days: {$elemMatch: {date: dayObj.day}}}}},
        update ={$push: {'rooms.???.days.$' : newDay} },
        options = {upsert: true};
    Building.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback());
```

I'm confused as to how my update parameter should reference the room as well as the day. What is the scope of the update parameter? I assume it is the whole document found/created?

Models:

```
var daySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   schedule: [{
       time: {type: String, required: true},
       activity: {type: String, required: true}
   }]
});

var roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    days: [{
        date: {type: String, required: true},
        schedule: {type: daySchema, required: true}
    }]
});

var buildingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //name: {type: String, required: true}
    code: {type: String, required: true},
    rooms: [roomSchema]
});
```